# for next loop failing to allocate a value to a variable - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am checking whether the 3 values selected in 3 different combo boxes are within a certain row. If they are, assign that row number to a variable, and if they aren't, check the next row. All cells in the range are filled with data, and the message boxes are bringing up the correct values (for checking purposes only) yet the If statement isn't moving to the `selectedrow = r` line in the code below.

```
Dim Project, licence, state As String
Dim selectedrow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim r As Integer


Project = cmb_Project.Value
licence = cmb_Licence.Value
state = cmb_State.Value


LastRow = Worksheets("Entitlements").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


    For r = 3 To LastRow
    MsgBox (Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 1).Value)
    MsgBox (Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 7).Value)
    MsgBox (Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 6).Value)
        If Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 1).Value = Project And _
            Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 7).Value = licence And _
            Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 6).Value = state Then

            selectedrow = r
         End If
    Next r
```

I'm guessing that I've made a stupid error, but any advice on how to remedy what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would also check the values of `Project`, `licence`, and `state`, and be very wary of leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Change your `MsgBox` statements to be something like `MsgBox "|" & Worksheets("Entitlements").Cells(r, 1).Value & "|" & vbCrLF & "|" & Project & "|"` - that will enable you to check both values at once, one above the other.  (As with others, I suspect there is a whitespace issue, or perhaps a case issue.)

Comment: And it would probably be a good idea to declare `Project` and `licence` as `String`, rather than having them defaulting to being declared as `Variant`.

Comment: Just a reminder, string comparison in VBA is case-sensitive. For the search you are doing, a `match` formula would be appropriate.

Comment: @YowE3K - thanks for that suggestion, I will certainly be stealing that for future debugging! :D helped confirm that there was no whitespace issues.

Comment: I'd warmly recommend using `Long` instead of `Integer` - *especially* since you're looking at worksheet rows here. A worksheet can have *a lot* more than 32,767 rows. And your computer loves 32-bit integers, too (that's a `Long`)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the issue here, but note that Project and License are not String variables, but Variants. When you `Dim` more than one variable on one line, each variable name has to have its own type. If no type is given, then the default is Variant.

So, try

```
Dim Project as String, license as String, state as String
```

Or, use three `Dim`statements instead of one.

Comment: @scb998 Out of curiousity, what were the values of `Project` and `licence`?  I wasn't expecting that to have solved it because a `Variant/String` and a `String` (or even a number) should have tested OK.

Comment: @YowE3K - licence is just 3 numbers, and the project is a unique combination of letters and numbers generated earlier in the process.

Comment: @YowE3K is correct, and as I flesh out in my answer, as long as one of the operands in the equality condition is a `String`, then VBA will do the implicit cast for you, but if one is `Variant\Double` and the other is a `Variant\String`, then you won't get equality.

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that the values in your ComboBox are *numeric* Strings, and the values in your ranges are numbers (and you've confirmed the license being 3 numbers).

Your code was failing because `Cells` returns a numeric cell as `Variant/Double`, and a `ComboxBox.Value` returns a `Variant/String`. Comparing those with an `=` operator results in an inequality.

You can see the same thing by entering `123` in Cell `E6`, then running this in the Immediate Window:

```
?Range("E6") = "123"
True
?Range("E6") = 123
True
?Range("E6") = CVar("123")
False
```

If you're comparing numbers, convert the values to numbers and then compare (But be careful, converting `"1D4"` and/or `"1E4"` to numbers results in `10000`), or convert the numbers to `Strings` and compare those.
Having at least one operand be a String is enough for Excel to perform a valid equality operation:

```
?Range("E6") = CStr(CVar("123"))
True
```

But convert both, and you can be sure of the right result.

```
?CStr(Range("E6")) = CStr(CVar("123"))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possibilities because of which the variable 'selectedrow' is not set to the row 'r'

1. Value of the variable 'LastRow' is calculated as less than 3. Due to this the loop is being skipped.
2. The if condition results to be false. Try it in immediate window or use watch to see the values stored in variables. Sometimes, a small space also negates the equality.

Comment: Your point 1 isn't valid because the OP said "the message boxes are bringing up the correct values", which means that the loop isn't being skipped.  Your point 2 is almost certainly spot-on.